# Bash- Return a value from child process to parent

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script, bash-scripting

I am using the below code

```
record_count=0
task()
{
while read -r record ; do
record_count=$(( record_count + 1 ))
.....
done < $1
}

for i in {1..5}; do
task $i &
done
```

how can i use the record_count from subshell\child process to parent shell\process.
I tried with `return record_count` but it does not work.
is there any another way to return the values ( if possible more than one value to return)

Comment: Since you're running tasks in the background, your question is similar to this one: [*How to assign environment variables in parallel in bash?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356221/108618) Note the most standard way of reporting the result is to print it to stdout. Does your current code (`task`) print anything to stdout?

Comment: @saiprudhvi: You can not use `return` in a subshell (as you suggested), but only for returning from a function or a sourced script. In your case, the `return` would be from a function; so this is OK. However, the argument of `return` must be a (small) number. `record_count` is a number only in a arithmetic context (i.e. within `((....))` or after a `let`.. `return` does not have arithmetic context, and you need to write either `return $record_count` or `return $((record_count))`. The returned value can be picked up on the calling side via `$?`.

Answer (score 1):

"return" is for the exit code, normally "0" indicating success, and anything else a failure.
And it must be an integer less than 256, so generally it's not useful for returning the kind of results expected here.

But your sub-processes can produce their results as text, and the main process can then optionally capture those results:

```
record_count=0
task()
{
    while read -r record
    do
        record_count=$(( record_count + 1 ))
    done <$1
    echo $record_count
}

(
    for i in {1..5}
    do
        task $i &
    done
    wait
) \
| sort
```

The "wait" ensures that all the sub-processes have finished before proceeding.

Note that with parallel processes, there's no guarantee as to what order they will finish in, so the results won't necessarily appear in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 order.

If that random order is a problem, the program could pass in a "key" to the task, and that key could be used to sort the output.
In this case $i itself could be the key, but in general the names of files won't be simple integers.

Comment: Here the results are short, each printed by a single `echo`. In general the results can get interleaved. [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) can help: `GNU parallel makes sure output from the commands is the same output as you would get had you run the commands sequentially`. (Not with a function though; `task` would need to be a standalone command).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return record_count` and get correct result only if the number is between 0 and 255.
And you should use the return code on this way:

```
for i in {1..5}; do
task $i ; echo $?
done
```